# Angular2 different templates

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I'm a bit stuck with the new angular2 architecture, i want to achieve a different templating depending on the component. For example, if i'm browsing the home page, i want the navigation and the footer as a template of my homepage that i can reuse in my account page.

Beside that, i would like to have the same behavior for all my /admin pages. The only way i found to resolve this is to create one component for each template, but that's a bit heavy no ?

Is there a better way to do that ?

[image: Figure 1 - Routing in angular2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the AsyncRoute isn't accessible any more, Angular 2 came up with a Lazy Loading function inside the routing system :

It's simple as this :

```
{
  path: 'admin',
  loadChildren: 'app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule',
}
```

Link : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#lazy-loading-route-config

Answer (score 2):

**Making an individual component allows you to reuse it when needed**.
I think making an individual component would be a greater choice because tomorrow you may want to add/play with some dynamic content.

> But its a bit heavy no ? **but in which context???**

you can also deal with **[AsyncRoute](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/AsyncRoute-class.html)** and call the route or component on the fly (**lazy loading**),

look at here - http://blog.mgechev.com/2015/09/30/lazy-loading-components-routes-services-router-angular-2/

Comment: Yes you're right, but i'm just using the components as a template interface, so it's not clean. By the way AsyncRoute looks perfect for this architecture !

Comment: Great ! yes it is.

Comment: I don't know about your though too much. But somewhere I guess DynamicComponentLoader could also help.